# R - Adding a line to a plot with lines() does not work - why?

Tags: r, plot, line, graphic

I am trying to put two lines on a graph. The data is coming from table of numeric variables:

```
> str(tab1)
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Cut_Point: num  -4.63 -2.85 -1.92 -1.86 -1.73 ...
 $ N_Samples: int  63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 ...
 $ Wilcoxon : num  0.0382 0.0382 0.0382 0.0382 0.0382 ...
 $ Cox_PH   : num  0.0571 0.0571 0.0571 0.0572 0.0572 ...
```

I thought this would be pretty simple so I wrote the following code:

```
plot(tab1$Cut_Point, -log10(tab1$Wilcoxon), type = "l", col = "red", main = "P-values vs Score", xlab = "Log10(Score)", ylab = "-Log10(P-Value)", ylim = c(0.5,1.5), xlim = c(-2,0.3))
coxline = -log10(tab1$Cox_PH)
lines(coxline, col = "blue")
abline(a = 1.122018, b = 0, col = "black")
legend("bottomright", c("Wilcoxon", "Cox PH", "P = 0.05"), lty = c(1,1,1),col = c("red", "blue", "black"))
```

Which produces the following graphic that is missing a blue line:

[image: DoesntWork]

The range of the two variables is not an issue as the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(tab1$Cut_Point, -log10(tab1$Cox_PH), type = "l", main = "Cox PH P-values vs Score", xlab = "Log10(Score)", ylab = "-Log(P-Value)", ylim = c(1, 1.5), xlim = c(-2,0.3))
abline(a = 1.122018, b = 0)
plot(tab1$Cut_Point, -log10(tab1$Wilcoxon), type = "l", main = "Wilcoxon P-values vs Score", xlab = "Log10(Score)", ylab = "-Log10(P-Value)", ylim = c(1,1.5), xlim = c(-2,0.3))
abline(a = 1.122018, b = 0)
```

produces the following graphic; notice that the top graph's line is defined exactly the same as the line that does not appear in the first graphic:

[image: Doesn'tWork2]

I have tried getting rid of the `xlim()` and `ylim()` arguments in the `plot()` command and have also tried creating a new column with `tab1$log_cox = -log10(tab1$Cox_PH)` but neither of these approaches make the elusive second blue line appear. 
None of my code produces error messages so I really have no clue why the second line does not appear. Alternate methods of producing a graph with both lines included are welcome **but what I really want to know and understand is why my code does not produce the blue line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the x values in your call to `lines()`; try:

```
lines(tab1$Cut_Point , coxline, col = "blue")
```